# VBA code to color mismatch data

Tags: excel, vba, colors, match

I'd like to know a piece of code that highlight when cell value is different from one sheet 1 to sheet 2.

For example in cell A2(sheet1) has Value asd24 and in cell A2(sheet2) has value asd25 then that particular cell must highlighted with any color either in sheet 1 or sheet 2.

I have already developed the with check the value of the cell:

```
Sub test()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
   Dim R As Range
strRangeToCheck = "A1:IV65536"
' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(strRangeToCheck) ' or whatever your other sheet is.
Debug.Print Now

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
        Else
            **/*/dont know what to do here*** 
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: to format the color simply use `varSheetA(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)` for color red. If you want to color it the same color is in the other sheet then use `varSheetA(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = varSheetB(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color`

Comment: Do you _need_ it to happen in VBA? This is trivial to implement with Conditional Formatting ("Use formula to determine which cells to format")?